# How to make a responsive hero image with css like bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is my HTML Code

```
<div id="hash-blog-section">
    <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
        <section class="page-img">
            <section class="hero">
                <h1>About Us!</h1>
                <p>
                    Dummy Data.
                </p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the internal CSS i am using on the particular page

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
@media screen and (min-width: 769px)
    {
        .page-img
            {
                margin-top: 63px;
                background: url('assets/img/about.jpg') no-repeat center;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                display: table;
                height: 450px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        .page-img .hero
            {
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
                display: table-cell;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        .page-img .hero h1, .page-img .hero p
            {
                color:#ffffff;
            }
    }
@media (max-width: 768px)
    {
        #hash-blog-section .page-img
        {
            margin-top: 59px;
        }
        .page-img
            {
                background: url('assets/img/about.jpg') no-repeat center;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                display: table;
                height: 250px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        .page-img .hero
            {
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
                display: table-cell;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        .page-img .hero p, .page-img .hero h1
            {
                color:#ffffff;
            }
        .page-img .hero p
            {
                text-align: justify;
                text-align-last: center;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
    }
```

I want to achieve a responsive hero image like bootstrap that will not crop and show every pixel of the image as it is while resizing the screen.

The problem is I have used in CSS `background-size: cover` which leads to cropping of the image at some points while resizing and at the small screen the whole image is cropped.

I also used in CSS `background-size: contain` but using this the image is responsive but in the cropped format from center;

How to achieve the responsiveness of the image?

Any helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use background-size: 100% 100%;

```css
.page-img
        {
            margin-top: 63px;
            background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6942095-abstract-background-wallpaper.jpg') no-repeat center;
            -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size:  100% 100%;
            -o-background-size:  100% 100%;
            background-size:  100% 100%;
            display:table;
             min-height: 450px;
          
            width: 100%;
        }
    .page-img .hero
        {
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
           
        }
    .page-img .hero h1, .page-img .hero p
        {
            color:#ffffff;
        }
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
.page-img{
        
    margin-top: 59px;
     height: 250px;
   }
  .page-img .hero p{
     text-align: justify;
     text-align-last: center;
     padding: 5px;
     font-size: 15px;     

 }
}
```

```html
<div id="hash-blog-section">
  <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
        <section class="page-img">
            <section class="hero">
                <h1>About Us!</h1>
                <p>
                    Dummy Data.
                </p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```